# How to compare data from 2 columns in same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help trying to get some data from table.
Lets say I have the table INSURANCE which has columns like these:

```
ID     NAME     NUMBER    OLD_NUMBER
1      STEVE     55        11,22,44
2      JOHN      77        33,66,77
3      PETER     99        88,99
```

I need to compare column NUMBER and OLD_NUMBER
(in OLD_NUMBER column, results are separated by comma)
and only show info when data from these columns have matched numbers.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: ***DON'T*** store multiple values as comma delimited strings.  ***EVER***.  It's about as ANTI-SQL as you can get.  Have a separate table with one row for each old value.

Comment: This is a terrible design and how you go about solving will depend on your particular RDBMS - tag the database you're using

Comment: Thanks, I'm very new to ddbb and I was asked to solved this, I'm going to follow your advice and tell the customer that there are better ways to manage this problem.

Answer (score 1):

apart that it is a not the best design and cause alot of headache for you and for your database engine , here is one way you can do this:

```
select *
from insurance
where 
 concat(',',OLD_NUMBER,',') like concat('%,',NUMBER,',%')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a horrible data model that you should fix.  However, you can do what you want, if you are stuck with someone else's really, really bad decisions.

In standard SQL, you can use `like` and string concatenation like this:

```
where ',' || old_number || ',' like '%,' || number || ',%'
```

The exact syntax may depend on the database you are using -- for instead `concat()` instead of `||`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will tell my superior that the data model the customer is giving me isn't good and they should change it.